# Is it possible to limit the locales for asset meta fields?

Tags: assets, localization

I am working on a multi-lingual site that contains a few sections in 5 languages (de, en, es, fr, ja). Most of the content however exists only in two languages (de, en). For regular content sections I can indicate which locales should be available. However, I could not find a way to limit the locales for asset meta fields in a similar way.

Background: Why do I want to limit the number of locales?

My site contains a large number of product descriptions. Each product description can have multiple assets. Each asset has a (*non-translatable*) type (e.g. image, PDF, audio sample) and a (*translatable*) caption. The captions exist only in the de and en locales. When I import the assets in craft (with a plugin), a content entry for every locale will be created and this leads to a very bloated content table.

- Can I just delete the unwanted entries in the content table?
- Should I use a different setup for storing assets (e.g. a special content section with a file field and not asset meta fields)?

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I just delete the unwanted entries in the content table?

No, definitely don’t do that.

If you only want to enter captions in a couple languages, fine. Just ignore the other locales.

Then from your templates you can always have Craft fetch the assets with the DE or EN content, by setting the `locale` param.

```twig
{% set assetLocale = (craft.locale == 'en' ? 'en' : 'de') %}

{% for asset in entry.myAssetsField.locale(assetLocale) %}
    {{ asset.caption }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I was wondering if I should just leave the assets as is and create a separate entry that contains a reference to the file and the metadata.